# How to handle Maui Handler property changed

Tags: c#, maui

I tried to convert a xam renderer to a Maui hadler and I got it all working except for my custom controls property changing. On my custom control when the border color changes it is not updated in the view. How do I handle this?

my Handler map for Android:

```
    public static void Map(IElementHandler handler, IElement view)
    {
        if (view is CustomEntry)
        {
            var control = (EntryHandler)handler;
            var viewData = (CustomEntry)view;

            var gd = new GradientDrawable();
            
            gd.SetColor(viewData.BackgroundColor.ToAndroid());
            gd.SetCornerRadius((int)handler.MauiContext?.Context.ToPixels(viewData.CornerRadius));
            gd.SetStroke((int)handler.MauiContext?.Context.ToPixels(viewData.BorderThickness), viewData.BorderColor.ToAndroid());
            control.PlatformView?.SetBackground(gd);

            var padTop = (int)handler.MauiContext?.Context.ToPixels(viewData.Padding.Top);
            var padBottom = (int)handler.MauiContext?.Context.ToPixels(viewData.Padding.Bottom);
            var padLeft = (int)handler.MauiContext?.Context.ToPixels(viewData.Padding.Left);
            var padRight = (int)handler.MauiContext?.Context.ToPixels(viewData.Padding.Right);

            control.PlatformView?.SetPadding(padLeft, padTop, padRight, padBottom);
        }
    }

How the controls properties are added:
    public class CustomEntry : Entry
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty PlaceholderFontSizeProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(PlaceholderFontSize), typeof(double), typeof(CustomEntry), -1d);
        public static BindableProperty CornerRadiusProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(CornerRadius), typeof(int), typeof(CustomEntry), 0);

        public static BindableProperty BorderThicknessProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(BorderThickness), typeof(int), typeof(CustomEntry), 0);

        public static BindableProperty PaddingProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Padding), typeof(Thickness), typeof(CustomEntry), new Thickness(5));

        public static BindableProperty BorderColorProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(BorderColor), typeof(Color), typeof(CustomEntry), Colors.Transparent);

        public int CornerRadius
        {
            get => (int)GetValue(CornerRadiusProperty);
            set => SetValue(CornerRadiusProperty, value);
        }

        public int BorderThickness
        {
            get => (int)GetValue(BorderThicknessProperty);
            set => SetValue(BorderThicknessProperty, value);
        }
        public Color BorderColor
        {
            get => (Color)GetValue(BorderColorProperty);
            set => SetValue(BorderColorProperty, value);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// This property cannot be changed at runtime in iOS.
        /// </summary>
        public Thickness Padding
        {
            get => (Thickness)GetValue(PaddingProperty);
            set => SetValue(PaddingProperty, value);
        }

        public double PlaceholderFontSize
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(PlaceholderFontSizeProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PlaceholderFontSizeProperty, value); }
        }
    }
```

How I am adding the Handler:

```
Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ElementHandler.ElementMapper.AppendToMapping(nameof(CustomEntry), (handler, view) =>
        {
            if (view is CustomEntry)
            {
                CustomEntryMapper.Map(handler, view);
            }
        });
```

Any idea how to make it update when the custom controls property updates?

Comment: You can also check the official doc: [Customize controls with handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/customize?view=net-maui-8.0) to get more information.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the code you provided, and find that these codes don't work:

```cs
gd.SetCornerRadius((int)handler.MauiContext?.Context.ToPixels(viewData.CornerRadius));
gd.SetStroke((int)handler.MauiContext?.Context.ToPixels(viewData.BorderThickness), viewData.BorderColor.ToAndroid());
control.PlatformView?.SetBackground(gd);
```

However, if you want to modify border of Entry, you can use [`Border`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/border?view=net-maui-8.0): View newly provided by MAUI.

```xml
<VerticalStackLayout
    Padding="30,0"
    Spacing="25">
    
    <Border Stroke="Black"
            StrokeThickness="2"
            BackgroundColor="SkyBlue">

        <Border.StrokeShape>
            <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="50"/>
        </Border.StrokeShape>

        <Entry Placeholder="type someting"
               PlaceholderColor="Grey"
               Margin="15,0"/>
    </Border>
    
</VerticalStackLayout>
```

code behind:

```cs
   public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
       public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ModifyEntry();
        }
        void ModifyEntry()
        {
            Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.EntryHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("MyCustomization", (handler, view) =>
            {
#if ANDROID
                handler.PlatformView.Background = null;
#elif IOS
                handler.PlatformView.BorderStyle=UIKit.UITextBorderStyle.None;
#endif
            });
        }
   }
```

Here is the effect: [Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6bLJ.png), [iOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNFVZ.png).